# Update data from an added prop on a collection with transform

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

this is my first question on Stack Overflow so feel free to ask me to be more accurate.

I have a collection with MongoDB on my meteor server. With the transform option, i add a simple selected property that can be toggle:

```
Nodes = new Mongo.Collection("nodes", {
    transform : function(item) {
       item.selected = false;

       item.toggleSelected = function() {
           item.selected = !item.selected;
       }

       return item;
    }
});
```

I added a function `toggleSelected` because I cannot modify the property selected with the Update function of meteor (or maybe I just don't know how). So this brings me to the problem where I show my list of `Nodes`. On this list I can select and unselect each nodes, and when I select it, I want the UI with React to update itself so that we can see that the node is selected :

```
Node = React.createClass({
   propTypes: {
   node: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   },
   render() {
      return (
         <li onClick={this.toggleSelected}>
            <span>{this.props.node.text}</span>
            <span className="single-node">Selected : {this.props.node.selected?"true":"false"}</span>
         </li>
      );
   },

   toggleSelected(){
       this.props.node.toggleSelected();    
   }
});
```

I already know about the forceUpdate() function but I don't want to use beacause it remove the data driven UI. I need to keep the `selected` property in the Mongo collection because I have an other view that depends on the value of this `selected` value.